# Regex for href value in Groovy

Tags: groovy

What's the best way in Groovy to capture a link's href value with regex?

`example: <a href="`**http://someurl.com**`">some link</a>`

I want to capture just what's in bold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you're picking the anchor tag out of, but if you have that isolated to what you have shown, the following should work:

```
def link= """<a href="http://someurl.com">some "link</a>"""
def url = (x =~ /\"(.*?)\"/)[0][1]
```